# How to display PointGeometryModel3D in GroupModel3D via Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx

I am using SharpDX to load and display models.

```
<hx:Viewport3DX  EffectsManager="{Binding EffectsManager}" 
                   Camera="{Binding Camera}" ModelUpDirection="0,0,1">
    <hx:AmbientLight3D Color="{StaticResource ModelAmbientLightColor}" />
    <hx:DirectionalLight3D Direction="{Binding Camera.LookDirection}" Color="{StaticResource ModelDirectionalLightColor}" />
    <hx:Element3DPresenter Content="{Binding MainModel}" />
    <hx:GroupModel3D ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfAdditionalModels}"/>
  </hx:Viewport3DX>
```

The list 'ListOfAdditionalModels' is an ObservableElement3DCollection of MeshGeometryModel3D.
This works as expected. All models/3d items get displayed correctly.

Now I want basically to do the same for a list of PointGeometryModel3D. But it would not display anything.

```
<hx:Viewport3DX EffectsManager="{Binding EffectsManager}" 
                Camera="{Binding Camera}" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" 
                 > 
    <hx:AmbientLight3D Color="#030303" />
    <hx:DirectionalLight3D Direction="{Binding Camera.LookDirection}" Color="White" />
    <hx:GroupModel3D ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPointCloudModels, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
    </hx:GroupModel3D>
```

What's wrong with this? I guess I have to tell the GroupModel to use the 'Geometry' property of its items. But I don't know how.

Using the one PointGeometryModel3D from the List 'ListOfPointCloudModels' directly works fine:

```
<hx:Viewport3DX EffectsManager="{Binding EffectsManager}" 
            Camera="{Binding Camera}" BackgroundColor="#FF88AACD" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" >
    <hx:AmbientLight3D Color="#030303" />
    <hx:DirectionalLight3D Direction="{Binding Camera.LookDirection}" Color="White" />
    <hx:PointGeometryModel3D Color="{x:Static Colors.White}"  
                             Geometry="{Binding PointsModel.Geometry}" Figure="Rect" Size="10 10" >          
    </hx:PointGeometryModel3D>
  </hx:Viewport3DX>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using an ItemsModel3D instead of GroupModel3d and defining the item template:

```
<hx:ItemsModel3D ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPointCloudModels}" >
      <hx:ItemsModel3D.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <hx:PointGeometryModel3D Geometry="{Binding Geometry}" Color="{x:Static Colors.White}" Figure="Rect" Size="2 2"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </hx:ItemsModel3D.ItemTemplate>
    </hx:ItemsModel3D>
```